# How Do I Get My Search Button To Function With This JS Code?

Tags: javascript, html, google-search

I have a custom search bar but I don't know how to get it to function with a js code.

This is my Search Button:

```js
script type = "text/javascript" >
  document.getElementById('searchform').onsubmit = function() {
    window.location = 'http://www.google.com/search?q=site:yourdomainname ' + document.getElementById('test').value;
    return false;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<center>
  <html>

  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
      input[type=text] {
        width: 130px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        border: 2px solid #000000;
        border-radius: 4px;
        font-size: 16px;
        background-color: white;
        background-image: url('searchicon.png');
        background-position: 10px 10px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
        -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
        transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
      }
      
      input[type=text]:focus {
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>

    <form>
      <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search..">
    </form>

  </body>

  </html>
```

If you can help me that would be great, thank you.

Comment: What version of Java is this? I don't think I've seen it before

Comment: I got it from this post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207309/how-do-i-get-my-search-bar-to-actually-work look at the answer that was posted below and you'll see it. I'm trying to use the same method but different button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no element `searchform` nor `test` declared in your html that you could `getElementById`.

Change your form to something like this:

```
<form id="searchform">
  <input id="test" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search..">
</form>
```